# Django 1.8- Turkish Letters Cause Exception

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm learning Django, and I've made my first project. When I run, it gives me error. I use Django 1.8 with Python 3.4.3 and PyCharm.

```
(unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte (views.py, line 7)
```

This is views.py:

```
__author__ = 'Ali Keskin'
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import *
def index(request):
    mesaj="Merhaba Django!"
    baslik="Merhaba Dünya"
    return render_to_response('index.html',locals())
```

The problem is the 'ü' character in "Merhaba Dünya." When I change 'ü' to 'u', it works well. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Pycharm encodign]

1. Make sure the file encoding is utf-8 (check `alt+ctrl+s` pycharm settings).
2. Tell python that file is encoded with utf-8 bu simply adding `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` as first row of the file.